# issue with objectid of mongodb in prisma client

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

Malformed ObjectID: invalid character '-' was found at index 8 in the provided hex string: "135a20ad-3244-46ed-80cf-a09a37ae4e85" for the field 'id'."

im getting error while trying to create a new record in my database using prisma

i tried by removing default value of id (auto) and re-generating the prisma client, but still i get the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend checking out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation, especially the part about including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Because with the current state of the question, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is cause by wrong field of the Model. You can include a snippet with the models. Especially mixing

```
String with @db.ObjectId
```

when it should be only String